# Laravel - permissionTrait.php

Tags: laravel, permissions, traits

I am new in Laravel development and I don't know why the **Route** is underlined like that :
Should I declare **Route**, above? I tried btw...
Anyone?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvNDi.png)

Comment: Include code and relevant errors in your question. Do not include pictures. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import it:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

But, your code is fine! Because, you call the Route facades! So, no need to to import.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed! I imported in fact!

Answer (score 0):

disable your php plugin in visual studio code